# R is equivalence relation in A?

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

Let $f: \{1,2,3,4\} \to \{1,2,3,4\}$ be a function. We define the set of functions "$A = \{g: \{1,2,3,4\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}\}$"
the relation $R$ given by

$gRh$ if and only if $g \circ f = h \circ f$

i)prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$

ii)assuming that $f$ is surjective, calculate the equivalence class of $g \in A$

OK. The first problem I have is that it already confuses me with that set "$A$" that has a function inside.
I always work with $X = \{n\in N: n <2019\}$ for example ... I know what  reflexivity, Symmetry, asymmetry and transitivity are ... but I honestly don't know how to face this problem. On the other hand I know that an equivalence relation means that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
That is, if it is $g\circ f = h\circ f$, does that mean that the function $g =$ the function $h$?
If you could help me it would be great.

Comment: The statement that $g\circ f=h\circ f$ just means that $g(f(x))=h(f(x))$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$ (which is $\{1,2,3,4\}$).  So two functions $g$ and $h$ are equivalent if they have the same output when applied to any output of $f$.  (If $f(x)$ is always $2$, for instance, then $gRh$ if and only if $g(2)=h(2)$.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Fixed your formatting this time.  It is definitely worth learning MathJax ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is a set of functions, in particular the set of all functions that map the numbers $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.  For example, if $g(1) = 5, g(2)= 3, g(3) = 3, g(4) = 7$m then $g$ is an element of $A$.

So say you want to know if $R$ is reflexive.  Is $gRg$ for every $g$, in other words.  That is defined as $g \circ f = g \circ f$, so yes, it is reflexive.

If math is getting too abstract, make a concrete example.  Suppose $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 3, f(4) = 3$